# Using an autowired singleton bean in a non spring managed java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Alright, this might seem pretty stupid to all the veterans out there, but bear with me here, as I'm only finding my way around Spring & Spring Boot.

I've got a Controller class here,

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Controller.class);

    private static Controller controller = null;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationParameters applicationParameters;

    public static Controller getInstance() {
        if (controller == null) {
            synchronized (Controller.class) {
                if (controller == null) {
                    controller = new Controller();
                }
            }
        }
        return controller;
    }

    public Controller() {}

    public ApplicationParameters getApplicationParameters() {
        return applicationParameters;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void init() {
        try {
            for (Entry<String, String> prop : applicationParameters.getProperties().entrySet())
                logger.info("Loaded System Property: " + prop.getKey() + " -> " + prop.getValue());

                Utils.concatenate("key1", "key2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

which autowires the `ApplicationParameters` bean with properties from a Property file.

Utils Class

```
public class Utils {

protected static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Utils.class);

    //Need to get the value of the property keys propKey1 & propKey2 and concat them.
    public static String concatenate(String propKey1, String propKey2) throws Exception {
        if(StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(propKey2) && StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(propKey1)) {
            return Controller.getInstance().getApplicationParameters().getProperties().get(propKey1) + Controller.getInstance().getApplicationParameters().getProperties().get(propKey2)
        } else {
            logger.error("System Property is undefined." );
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So, I'd like use this autowired `ApplicationParameters` bean as a **singleton** instance throughout the lifecycle of my project.

For instance, I'd like to use it in the `Utils` class. Clearly `Utils` class is not spring managed, its just a regular old java class.

**So I'd like to know how to use fully initialized applicationParameters in my Utils class.**

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Autowiring the `ApplicationParameters` again in the `Utils` class, like this,

   ```
   public class Utils {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationParameters applicationParameters;

   protected static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Utils.class);
   ```

But `applicationParameters` will be `null` here as, I'm presuming, this is because, `Utils` is not a spring managed bean.

2. Make `Controller` class singleton. (Not sure how to go about doing this as init() needs to get invoked when web server starts, then where to call getInstance()?)

Hence, would someone be so kind as to assist a novice here.

P.S. The Utils class is shown only as a sample to bring home the fact that, a spring managed autowired bean has to be used in a regular java class.

Comment: is your Util class annotated with Service/Controller/Component? otherwise Autowired annotation that you used inside the class is not working.  Also you can annotate your init method with PostConstruct instead of RequestMapping.

Comment: your singleton implementation could be wrong.  while you put a public constructor in a class, someone still can create a new instance of that class.  you should make constructors private, so they can access the class instance by only the getInstance method. it is better re-read again spring bean scope, singleton, prototype document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the spring context accessible from outside with a helper class like this one:

```
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
   static ApplicationContext applicationContext;     

   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
     applicationContext = context;
   }

   public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
     return applicationContext;
   }
}
```

Then, you could do something like this: `SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext.getBean("applicationParameters")`

Comment: Hi, Is there any way I could use my Controller class itself as a singleton instance?

Comment: You could probably initialize the static controller field in the constructor of the controller. But then you end up with a controller dependency in the util class.

Comment: `You could probably initialize the static controller field in the constructor of the controller`. Could you maybe help me with that. I'm not sure where to call the getInstance() for initial initialization of the static controller field

Comment: `public Controller() {controller = this;}`

Answer (score -1):

As a first rule, don't. A second don't either. Only if you really must, as there is no garantuee that this will work reliable as there is no way that everything has been properly initialized when this method is called. Instead try re-working your util to be a spring managed class as well.

If you really want, ditch most of your code as you are trying to be too smart in your code. Use this hack (yes it is a hack imho and should be avoided if necessary!).

```
public class SpringUtil {

  private static final ApplicationContext ctx;

  SpringUtil(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    SpringUtil.ctx=ctx;
  }

  public static Controller getController() {
    return this.ctx.getBean(Controller.class);
  }

  public static ApplicationParameters getApplicationParameters() {
    return ctx.getBean(ApplicationParameters.class);
  }
}
```

Then cleanup your controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Controller.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationParameters applicationParameters;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public void init() {
        try {
            for (Entry<String, String> prop : applicationParameters.getProperties().entrySet())
                logger.info("Loaded System Property: " + prop.getKey() + " -> " + prop.getValue());

                Utils.concatenate("key1", "key2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

THen use the `SpringUtil` to obtain the `ApplicationParameters` instead of the controller

```
public class Utils {

protected static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Utils.class);

    //Need to get the value of the property keys propKey1 & propKey2 and concat them.
    public static String concatenate(String propKey1, String propKey2) throws Exception {
        if(StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(propKey2) && StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(propKey1)) {
            return SpringUtils.getApplicationParameters().getProperties().get(propKey1) + SpringUtils.getApplicationParameters().getProperties().get(propKey2)
        } else {
            logger.error("System Property is undefined." );
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However this is quite a hack and might work in 90% of the cases. Also there is quite a design flaw/smell as you are doing a lot of getter chaining in your class. So all in all you are probably better of refactoring the `Utils` to make use of regular method calls and proper design techniques.